# sparse matrix multiplication in torch c++

Tags: sparse-matrix, libtorch

I know that in the pytorch, you can use torch.sparse.mm(mat1,mat2) to do matrix multiplication between two sparse matrix. I wonder that if there is a function in torch c++ that can do the same thing(two sparse matrix mul)? I tried to use mat1.mm(mat2), but it seems like it only supports mat2 to be dense.
Thanks in advance!